# Change ViewController MacOS Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, viewcontroller

I have two view controllers in two different storyboards:

Story board #1:[Main.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fKTQC.png)

This is connected to a class called: ViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa
class ViewController: NSViewController {

//Bad Button Attempt:
    /*override func prepareForSegue(segue: NSStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        //1
        let CareViewCont
        rol = segue.destinationController as! NSViewController
        //2
        self.dismissViewController(self)
    }*/


    //Rest of Default Code:
    @IBOutlet weak var findButton: NSButton!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        }
    }
}
```

Storyboard #2: [Ashwin.Storyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiNbr.png)

This is connected to a class called: CareViewController.swift:

```
import Cocoa
class CareViewController: NSViewController {

//empty

}
```

Basically all I want to do is click the "Find" button in Main.Storyboard and have that switch the view controller to the one in Ashwin.Storyboard.

I have tried copy and pasting the ViewController in Ashwin.Storyboard to Main.Storyboard, control clicking the find button, and creating a "Action Segue" but all of the action segues make a new window pop up and that's not what I want.

I have also tried making an action listener for the "Find" button in ViewController.Swift but I couldn't make that approach work... (I have a feeling that's the solution though...)

Please help me I'm clueless in MacOS.

Answer (score 0):

Add a storyBoard reference to the main.storyboard canvas. Then segue from the find button to the reference. select the storyboard reference on the canvas and in the attributes inspectors set it to your Ashwin.storyboard

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I still have a problem where all the segue types (Show, Modal, Sheet, or Popover) all make a new window instead of just changing the view controller. Do I need to make a custom segue?

Comment: Did you set the storyboard reference in the attributes inspector? I don't have much experience with macOS app.

Comment: I just made a small test on my iMac and this does indeed work I don't really know what else is going on with your application